# Display Port via USB-c

Tags: usb, displayport

I cannot get display port via usb-c working. I've tried 2 cables but no success. Xrandr simply can't see the external screen. I'm sure I'm missing any configuration or installed package but I have no idea where to start.

```
~ » uname -a 
Linux box 4.16.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.16.5-1 (2018-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I plug in the screen (which has also built-in USB hub) I get this.

```
Jun 27 21:54:23 box kernel: [  208.841807] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_GPE.XTBT.SPRT], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180105/dswload2-350)
Jun 27 21:54:23 box kernel: [  208.841826] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180105/psobject-252)
Jun 27 21:54:23 box kernel: [  208.841834] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_GPE.XTBT, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180105/psparse-550)
Jun 27 21:54:23 box kernel: [  208.841847] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_GPE.XTBT, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180105/psparse-550)
Jun 27 21:54:23 box kernel: [  208.841861] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_GPE._E42, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180105/psparse-550)
Jun 27 21:54:23 box kernel: [  208.841873] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, while evaluating GPE method [_E42] (20180105/evgpe-646)
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.956323] pci 0000:01:00.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.956413] pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.956540] pci 0000:01:00.0: supports D1 D2
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.956544] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.957134] pci 0000:02:00.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.957232] pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.957371] pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1 D2
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.957376] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.957604] pci 0000:02:01.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.957701] pci 0000:02:01.0: enabling Extended Tags
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.957840] pci 0000:02:01.0: supports D1 D2
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.957844] pci 0000:02:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.958060] pci 0000:02:02.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.958157] pci 0000:02:02.0: enabling Extended Tags
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.958323] pci 0000:02:02.0: supports D1 D2
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.958328] pci 0000:02:02.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.958606] pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-39]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.958627] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xda0fffff]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.958642] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.958769] pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.958789] pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xda000000-0xda0fffff]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.958919] pci 0000:02:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04-38]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.958938] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xd9efffff]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.958952] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.959144] pci 0000:39:00.0: [8086:15b5] type 00 class 0x0c0330
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.959205] pci 0000:39:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9f0ffff]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.959332] pci 0000:39:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.959504] pci 0000:39:00.0: supports D1 D2
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.959510] pci 0000:39:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.959876] pci 0000:02:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 39]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.959896] pci 0000:02:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9ffffff]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.959956] pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960021] pci 0000:02:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 04-38] add_size 1000
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960043] pci 0000:02:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 39] add_size 1000
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960052] pci 0000:02:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960074] pci 0000:01:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 02-39] add_size 2000
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960085] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x2000]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960091] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x2000]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960096] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x2000]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960100] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x2000]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960111] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960115] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960118] pci 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960123] pci 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960135] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960142] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960155] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960161] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960168] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960173] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960180] pci 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960186] pci 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960194] pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960208] pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xda000000-0xda0fffff]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960228] pci 0000:02:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04-38]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960241] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xd9efffff]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960252] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960267] pci 0000:02:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 39]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960279] pci 0000:02:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9ffffff]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960298] pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-39]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960311] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xda0fffff]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.960321] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.963686] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.963714] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.964938] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x00009810
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.965345] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.965352] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.965357] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.965363] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.16.0-1-amd64 xhci-hcd
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.965368] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:39:00.0
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.965779] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.965805] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.966925] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.966939] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.966949] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.967049] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.967055] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.967060] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.967065] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.16.0-1-amd64 xhci-hcd
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.967070] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:39:00.0
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.967478] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  213.967502] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  214.299702] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  214.459749] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0800, idProduct=0800
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  214.459755] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  214.459759] usb 3-1: Product: USB 2.0 BILLBOARD             
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  214.459763] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: VIA Technologies Inc.         
Jun 27 21:54:28 box kernel: [  214.459766] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 0000000000000001
```

I've also updated bios to the latest - no luck.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you sure your hardware supports display port via USB-C? What USB hardware do you have? What monitor do you have? Are you sure the USB port on the monitor supports display port, and isn't just a USB hub (which is the case for many monitors)?

Comment: I'm sure because vendor declares it. I guess u misunderstood. I have a cable with DP on one side and usb-c on the other. I plug usb-c to my laptop and the second end to the screen.

Also I guess my issue might be related to this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403318/usb-c-→-displayport-adapter-support?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

DisplayPort over USB-C "Alternate Mode" is coming to Linux in version 4.19.

Sources:

- First News: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-USB-Type-C-Port-DP-Driver
- Confirmation for release 4.19: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Type-C-DP-Alt-Mode-Linux-4.19
- Article Source: http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1806.3/03118.html

Comment: Confirmed. Running 4.19 and it works.